# Docker-Compose script not running

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm pretty new to Docker and especially to docker-compose and I'm running into an issue I can't seem to fix.

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file that looks like

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  backup:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: sh -c "while :;do sleep 5; done"
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - ./data:/app/data
```

and I have a file called `start.sh` that looks simple like

```
python3 -u ./upload_to_s3.py > log/upload_to_s3.f9beb4d9.out 2>&1 &
```

When I run `docker-compose exec backup /bin/sh` I can get onto the docker image and I can run `./start.sh` and it will run my processes which I can verify through a simple `ps aux`. However, when I run

`docker-compose exec backup sh start.sh`

it doesn't seem to run at all.

I try to verify by getting back onto the image and running `ps aux` and, in fact, the python script is not running.

What's going on? Why can't I seem to run my `start.sh` file using `docker-compose`?

EDIT: I've also tried to run this using `docker-compose run --rm --detach --entrypoint="sh" backup -c "/app/start.sh"`and I get the exact same issue

Comment: I think you have to worry a little bit about the base image and its entrypoint and also the command you run it with

Answer (score 0):

The script you show starts a background process.  But if that's run in the context of a `docker exec` debugging shell, as soon as the `docker exec` command completes, any background processes that are still running will get terminated.

I might run this in a temporary container instead of a `docker exec` session.  The important thing is to run this as a *foreground* process instead of launching a background job.  For example:

```sh
docker-compose run backup \
  ./upload_to_s3.py
```

[`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) will inherit many of the settings from the `backup` container, like its `image:` and `volumes:` mounts, but you get to specify the `command:` to run at the command line.  This also saves you the trouble of keeping a meaningless container alive so that you can `docker exec` into it later; just run a new container for these one-off tasks.

(Note, the specific invocation I've shown here assumes that the Python script is marked executable, with `chmod +x` if required; that it begins with a "shebang" line like `#!/usr/bin/env python3`; and that the image sets an environment variable `ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`.)

Comment: Thanks for this! Is there a way to run this shell script as a foreground process? I have a few other commands I was hoping to add to this `start.sh` and that's why I did it as a shell script where everything was run in the background?

Comment: When I run `docker-compose run --rm --detach --entrypoint="sh" backup -c "/app/start.sh"` I get the exact same issue

Comment: You should not need `--entrypoint` (your image may be incorrectly built if you do).  Did you change the `start.sh` script to run the job in the foreground?